# Vuetify set image background on navigation-drawer

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using one of Vuetify's material template for learning. Its `navigation-drawer` has an image on the background like so:

[image]

I've looked at the code and the navigation-drawer has a `v-img`component that gives it the image:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    id="app-drawer"
    v-model="inputValue"
    app
    dark
    floating
    persistent
    mobile-break-point="991"
    width="260">

    <v-img :src="image" height="100%">
```

However what I cannot understand is that the src property is binded to an image attribute which I was expecting to find in the data function but its not there. The only other reference image is being applied is in the computed properties like so:

```
computed: {
...mapState("app", ["image", "color"]),
```

How is the image being applied or where the actual source for the image is located?

Comment: Do read through vuex documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the vuetify material dashboard example app. You will find the image in teh vuex store.
More specifically - src/store/modules/app/state.js